# Save and Load PinnedShortcuts from Windows 7 Taskbar

Tags: windows, taskbar

I really like the Windows 7 taskbar but I would like to have different sets of icons instead of all of them fixed. These need have been increasing with the use of the new IE9's feature of Pinned Sites. I have a lot of sites of interest that I read depending on the task that I'm doing. So I need a way to organize all of this pinned sites and applications.

For example one could have different taskbar (set of pinned sites) for this purposes:

News and Social Updates

Mail, Appointments, and Organizing

Programing

Art and Painting

etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this site has reference [WinHelpOnline](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/backup-pinned-shortcuts-taskbar-windows-7/) i manage to create a script in Powershell that permits save and load PinnedSites. The load method need to be run with elevation. I post the code if someone finds it useful.

```
$PinnedRoot = "PathWhereYouWantToSavePinnedSites"
function Show-PinnedTI(){
   ls $PinnedRoot
}  
function Save-PinnedTI($name){
   REG EXPORT HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Taskband ($name +".reg")

$newDir = ($PinnedRoot + "\" + $name)
$name = $name+".reg"


mkdir $newDir -Force
Move-Item $name -Destination $newDir -Force
copy ($env:APPDATA+ "\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar") ($newDir+"\items") -Recurse
 }

function Load-PinnedTI($name)
{
   $newDir = ($PinnedRoot + "\" + $name)
   $nameReg = $name+".reg"
   $fullname = ($newDir + "\" + $nameReg)
   $a = gc $fullname
$b = [string]::join("`n", $a)
$b =  $b -replace "`"FavoritesResolve`"[^\`"]*", ""
set-content $fullname -value $b
Start-Process $fullname -Wait
Remove-Item ($env:APPDATA+ "\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar\*") -Recurse -Force
ls ($newDir+"\items") | %   {copy $_.fullname -Destination ($ENV:APPDATA+"\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar") -Recurse -Force}

kill -n explorer
```

}

Using this functions i can have the PinnedSites that i want depending in what i'm working. :)